# Using a value of the enum to serialize with Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, gson

I have two enums I've created for my Java project, and both of them need to be serialized and deserialized using Gson. The problem is, I need to use a value on each enum Field as the serialized value.

As an example, I have these enums:

[Options Enum](https://pastebin.com/nSKr2a12)

[Language Enum](https://pastebin.com/fFJE86zr)

My hope is that I am able to serialize both enums using the `key` value provided to both. This is a really simplified example, but it still perfectly describes my situation.

I tried using custom serializer classes for both:

[Options Serializer](https://pastebin.com/SfM2JCmQ)

[Language Serializer](https://pastebin.com/xtdsurqp)

And yes, I did register both using `registerTypeAdapter(type, adapter)`

The strange this is, it would work for one enum, serializing to the correct value, but not the other. I suspect it's because the class that's being serialized is formatted similar to this:

```
public class Item {
    public Language language;
    public List<Options> options;
}
```

Where in this case, `Language` is serialized properly, but the `Options` enum is not, just returning the enum value name.

I'm not sure if there's some special way I need to handle this, but it's getting frustrating.

**EDIT**: I know about using the `@SerializedName()` annotation, but both of the enums I'm using have hundreds of entries and the keys that are part of the enum are used elsewhere throughout the program as well. Using `@SerializedName()`, at least in my case, I don't think would be feasible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write an adapter for Item. I would add more but laptop on 1%.

```java
    static class ItemAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Item> {

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Item value) throws IOException {
            out.beginObject();
            out.name("language").value(value.language.key);
            out.name("options");
            out.beginArray();
            for (Option option : value.options) {
                out.value(option.key);
            }
            out.endArray();
            out.endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public Item read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();

            in.nextName();
            String languageKey = in.nextString();

            in.nextName();
            in.beginArray();

            List<String> optionKeys = new ArrayList<>();

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                optionKeys.add(in.nextString());
            }
            in.endArray();

            in.endObject();

            return new Item(Language.BY_KEY.get(languageKey),
                    optionKeys.stream()
                            .map(Option.BY_KEY::get)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So a TypeAdapter instead of using JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer?

Comment: @MattChris I downvoted this answer because it is misleading as it does not explain the difference between your implementations and this one. JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer are just a special kind of type adapters with JSON objects in-between that cost some performance. You implementations work **fine**. Are you sure you registered both enum type adapters? What is your real JSON result? How does the JSON enum outputs really differ? How did you create the Gson instance using GsonBuilder? How does the accepted answer resolve these questions?

Comment: The accepted answer solution has many flaws too: 1) Gson can handle the Item class itself including cool stuff like @SerializedName, field naming strategies; 2) what if you have another "item" class?; 3) this solution is null-intolerant; 4) it also totally ignores the real order of JSON properties on read; 5) it does not delegate instance lists instantiation to the Gson core.

Comment: @fluffy I already proposed an answer regarding SerializedName but the author noted that he had too many enumeration elements and that using SerializedName was not a viable solution. None the less, I appreciate the input however this is a viable solution.

Comment: @MattChris Yeah so the TypeAdapter will allow you to customize how you encode and decode the Enum which is what you want. You don't necessarily want to always encode the Language and Option enum using the given field, however in the specific case of an `Item` you want to encode and decode a specific way. That is why having a `TypeAdapter` for the `Item` is a viable solution.

Comment: Yeah, so what I ended up doing is writing the TypeAdapter, but the way I did it was looped `while (in.hasNext())` and checked the name each time. I did some verification to make sure I didn't set the same variable twice, but otherwise the values read from the JSON file are just saved to some temporary variables, then passed through to the class constructor. I realized that the solution proposed here would require all the information to be in the same order, which I knew wouldn't always be the case, so I did some extra magic to make it order independent.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. Never thought about order, good job.

Comment: @MattChris You guys both did it in a wrong way that led you even further. Making an arbitrary viable solution does not make the solution good. I claim that the accepted answer promotes a very bad approach that does not scale and makes an attempt of doing the job for Gson whilst the latter does it flexibly, efficiently and correctly. Again, the original enum type adapters **are** fine and the very core issue is most likely hidden in the `GsonBuilder` configuration, not the original enum type adapters.